# Making a html element that acts like a window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a window-like HTML element that functions like `window.open` but only works within the bounds of the page.

I've run into 3 problems:

1. The first being that I don't know how to change the size of it
2. How to open and close it I want to click on Icon and make it open and also how to close it. It's already draggable so that the one thing going for it.
3. How to set the initial position of it. if anyone has a better method cause I'm still super new to coding and just got this off of W3schools anything would be useful.

[This is what I want my end goal to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LKyq.jpg)

```
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question might be better received if you narrowed it down a bit, and made it more specific. As-is, it's pretty broad, and hard to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size - to change the size of an element you can simply edit the its `style.width` and `style.height`. If you would like to have a draggable resizing cursor, like with a real window, you would need to create a transparent element that covers the resizing activation areas, and listen to its events like you listen to the window dragging.

Initial position - just like you set the dragged position, you can set an initial one.

As for the opening and closing, you would most likely need to restructure the app a bit and build some abstractions. Try to think of a way to have a `createNewWindow` function that accepts arbitrary HTML content and just shows a window. Within that function you would add a "header" to the content, add resizing areas, add close/minimize/maximize buttons, add the window to a global array of windows (so that you can display a bottom bar with window titles and unminimize when needed).

There's no single answer here, you can build an app like that in a million different ways. Focus on abstracting things away.